# C++ pass by reference local variable

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I'm new to c++

I have following class:

```
class User
{
public:
    User(const string& username) {
         m_username = username;
    }

    string username() const {
        return m_username;
    }

    void setUsername(const string &username) {
        m_username = username;
    }

private:
    string m_username;
};
```

Here is main.cpp code

```
User *createUser() {
    string username = "someUser";
    User *u = new User(username);
    return u;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    User *u2 = createUser();
    cout << u2->username() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In function `createUser()` I'm creating local variable `username` and pass it by reference to `User class` constructor. When function ends, variable `username` goes out of scope, therefore value of `m_username` member of class `User` should 
deleted.

But is still accessible outside of this function, e.g. main method prints "someUser" to console.

Why?

Comment: The `username` local variable in `createUser` goes out of scope and is deleted. The `m_username` member variable in the `User` instance is a completely separate variable.

Answer (score 6):

The `username` local variable in `createUser` goes out of scope and is deleted.

The `m_username` member variable in the `User` instance is a completely separate variable, and it is not deleted at that point, because there's no reason it would be deleted.

This has nothing to do with whether you pass it to the constructor by reference or not.

You might be thinking of a similar but different situation - if `m_username` *was a reference* to the local variable (instead of being a completely unrelated variable) you would have a problem:

```
class User
{
public:
    User(const string& username)
        : m_username(username)
    {
    }

    string username() const {
        return m_username; // <---- Undefined behaviour HERE
        // where the variable that m_username refers to is accessed,
        // but that variable's already been destroyed.
    }

private:
    const string &m_username; // <---- now a reference
};

Here is main.cpp code

User *createUser() {
    string username = "someUser";
    User *u = new User(username);
    return u;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    User *u2 = createUser();
    cout << u2->username() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: username variable is passed by reference and than copied when assigning to m_username, right?

Comment: @moreo That is correct. (In your code, of course, not the code in this answer where m_username is a reference)

Answer (score 2):

> When function ends, variable username goes out of scope, therefore
>   value of m_username member of class User should deleted.

That's not right. I don't see the implementation of your User constructor, but i guess it just does a copy of given string. `m_username` has no further link to your local variable, it's an own instance.